# BigQuery: billing and quotas

Tags: google-bigquery, dml

We had a strange incidence two days ago, while trying to run insert queries on BigQuery. Both the console and api gave us this error (two different tables and inserts):

"Billing has not been enabled for this project. Enable billing at https://console.cloud.google.com/billing. DML queries are not allowed in the free tier. Set up a billing account to remove this restriction."

It was strange because we didn't face this issue before, not with insert queries and not with any other such queries, but we eventually decided to move from using them (the insert) and loaded the data with files instead.

Today the error is gone for the insert queries.
I am sure we didn't pass the daily restriction of 1000 updates per table - especially not for the table I was trying to insert the data to.

Anyone has an idea what could have happened?

Also, does anyone know if loading data from files is always free of charge? (we didn't face any issues with that but we are unable to understand that from the docs..)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

FYI, The loading from files is free so far. However the restrictions on 1000 DML actions per table has been relaxed as of March 03 
See https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dml-without-limits-now-in-bigquery

However, I saw that the rate at which the DMLs are done on a single table is still under quotas. Many a times it fails, with `Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table`

From your issue, looks like the Billing Account was temporarily unavailable. Check with billing administrators